# Calculating the sum of array-based terms in SymPy [ValueError: Invalid limits given]

Tags: python, numpy, math, sum, sympy

I have been trying to obtain some numerical outputs from the sum below. It needs to give numerical outputs normally. However, I receive an error related to the limits.

I have a sum with a low boundary of `i = 0` and an upper boundary of `i = k-1` mathematically. I took `(i, 0, k)` because the last term is excluded by SymPy, Sum. Besides, I need to get the result within this nested for loop. **Could there be a mismatch between for loops and sum?** Even so, I cannot change for loops for `k` and `Nt`. Here, `k` depends on the `Nt`.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from sympy import Sum

Nx = 31          
Nt = 17
tau = .85 / Nt   
u = np.ones((Nt, Nx)) * np.sin(np.pi)
Sigma = np.zeros((Nt, Nx))   

for k in range(1, Nt): 
  for i in range(1, k):
    for j in range(1, Nx-1):   
      #define sum
      Sigma[i, j] = Sum( ((u[i+1][j] - u[i][j]) / tau * 97.1), (i, 0, k)).doit()    
      print(Sigma[i, j])
```

Error:

```
---> 16       Sigma[i, j] = Sum( ((u[i+1][j] - u[i][j]) / tau * 97.1), (i, 0, k) ).doit()

ValueError: Invalid limits given: ((1, 0, 2),)
```

Also, I am confused about `sum`, `Sum` or `summation`. None of these gave me a numerical result, or most likely I am not using these methods correctly. **How can I get the numerical outputs?** Again, I've tried `np.sum()` below.

```
for k in range(1, Nt): 
  for i in range(1, k):
    for j in range(1, Nx-1):   
      #define sum
      Sigma[i, j] = np.sum( ((u[i+1][j] - u[i][j]) / tau * 97.1), 0, k-1)    
      print(Sigma[i, j])
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0...
```

I think I cannot properly write the limits of the sum in `np.sum()`. How can I correct this? **How can I avoid 0 result?**

**EDIT:**
I used sum():

```
for k in range(1, Nt): 
  for i in range(1, k):
    for j in range(1, Nx-1):   
      #define sum
      Sigma[i, j] = sum(u[i+1][j] - u[i][j])
      print(Sigma[i, j])
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: sympy.Sum is for symbolic sums, you want np.sum or python's built-in sum function. It's not clear if you've read the documentation for any of these. If not, that would be your first step. If you're getting an unexpected result you're next step is to break the computation into its component pieces and examine each of these "subresults" to see where things are going wrong. You can use a debugger to step through the code to see the trouble happening. If a debugger is too complex to use at the moment you always print out these subresults appropriately labeled.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you for your answer. What is the difference between symbolic sums and normal(?) sums? Yes, I'm new to using Python. So if the debugger is a relatively complex build, it might be complicated for now.

Comment: This needs a [mcve] - not only a meaningful `u`, but also desired results.  Keep it small so you can demonstrate the calculations.  Forget about the `sympy.Sum/np.sum/sum` for now.  You haven't got the `u` and `k,i,j` iterations worked out.  I'm going to vote to close.

Comment: @hpaulj But why? There is a lot of valuable information provided by you and smchr below. People can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Reread the sympy docs.  I think they specify that `sum` should be used with:

```
 Sum(expr, (var, a, b)
```

(I probably shouldn't try to work from memory here, but you can check).

In your:

```
 Sum( ((u[i+1][j] - u[i][j]) / tau * 97.1), (i, 0, k))
```

`((u[i+1][j] - u[i][j]) / tau * 97.1)` is a number, derived from numpy `u`.  It isn't a sympy expression.

and `i` is a number, not sympy symbol.  The error tells us that "Invalid limits given: ((1, 0, 2),)".

For someone who is new to Python, trying to use `sympy` will be difficult.

The problem with

```
np.sum( ((u[i+1][j] - u[i][j]) / tau * 97.1), 0, k-1)
```

is that `np.sum` does not take limits like the sympy `Sum`.  Don't assume the documentation for one function applies to a similarly named one in another package.  `np.sum`, if you read its docs, takes an array, with optional parameters like `axis`.

As for your last attempt:

```
sum(u[i+1][j] - u[i][j])
```

the python `sum` takes an "iterable", something like a `list`.  `u[i+1][j] - u[i][j]` is a single number.

`u` is a 2d numpy array.  `u[i]` is a 1d array, a "row";, `u[i,j]` is a single element of the array.

What exactly are you trying to sum?

I suspect you have some sort of mathematical summation in mind, and have tried to express that with sympy algebra.  But your `u` is a 2d numpy array.  So `u[i+1,j]-u[i,j]` is a single number, the difference between two elements.  `u[1:,j]-u[:-1,j]` takes the difference between all such pairs of rows.

I haven't tried to figure out what your nested loops are doing, especially since `i` is a subset of possible rows.

### edit

Let's simplify your example a bit - smaller dimensions, and removing the constants that don't change the behavior:

```
In [5]: Nx = 4          
   ...: Nt = 3   
   ...: u = np.ones((Nt, Nx))
   ...: Sigma = np.zeros((Nt, Nx))   
   ...: 
   ...: for k in range(1, Nt):
   ...:   print('k',k) 
   ...:   for i in range(1, k):
   ...:     print('i',i)
   ...:     for j in range(1, Nx-1):
   ...:       print('j',j)   
   ...:       Sigma[i,j] = u[i+1,j] - u[i,j]   
   ...:   print(Sigma)
   ...:   
k 1
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
k 2
i 1
j 1
j 2
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

When `k` is 1, there's no `i` iteration since `range(1,1)` is empty.  So `Sigma` is still the original 0s.

For `k` 2, `i` ranges(1,2), i.e. once. `j` iterates range(1,3), i.e. 1 and 2.  But `Sigma` is still 0.  `u` is all ones, so paired differences are 0.  @smichr already pointed this out (I missed it on earlier reads).

```
In [3]: u
Out[3]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])

In [4]: u[1:]-u[:-1]
Out[4]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I'm not sure it's worth pursuing this further.  You need a realistic example where the `u` differences matter.  But keep it small (like this (4,3), so you can actually specify what values you seek.

If I define a `random` `u`:

```
In [13]: u
Out[13]: 
array([[14,  1,  1, 11],
       [ 2,  4, 17,  4],
       [11,  2,  6, 19]])

In [14]: u[1:]-u[:-1]
Out[14]: 
array([[-12,   3,  16,  -7],
       [  9,  -2, -11,  15]])
```

For `k` 1 sigma is still 0, but for `k` 2:

```
k 2
i 1
j 1
j 2
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  -2. -11.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

The code set the `Sigma[1,1]` and `Sigma[1,2]` values from the difference array.

Here's a sample run for a case with more rows:

```
In [16]: Nt,Nx = 5,4

In [17]: u = np.random.randint(0,20,(Nt,Nx))

In [18]: u
Out[18]: 
array([[18, 15, 17,  3],
       [ 9,  2,  5, 16],
       [11, 19,  5,  2],
       [13,  0,  4,  5],
       [ 8, 10, 10,  0]])

In [19]: u[1:]-u[:-1]
Out[19]: 
array([[ -9, -13, -12,  13],
       [  2,  17,   0, -14],
       [  2, -19,  -1,   3],
       [ -5,  10,   6,  -5]])

In [20]: Sigma = np.zeros((Nt, Nx))   
    ...: for k in range(1, Nt):
    ...:   print('k',k) 
    ...:   for i in range(1, k):
    ...:     print('i',i)
    ...:     for j in range(1, Nx-1):
    ...:       print('j',j)   
    ...:       Sigma[i,j] = u[i+1,j] - u[i,j]   
    ...:   print(Sigma)
    ...:   
k 1
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
k 2
i 1
j 1
j 2
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. 17.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
k 3
i 1
j 1
j 2
i 2
j 1
j 2
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  17.   0.   0.]
 [  0. -19.  -1.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]
k 4
i 1
j 1
j 2
i 2
j 1
j 2
i 3
j 1
j 2
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  17.   0.   0.]
 [  0. -19.  -1.   0.]
 [  0.  10.   6.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Let's try a case where successive `k` values are added to the original, rather than simply overwritting.

```
In [21]: Sigma = np.zeros((Nt, Nx))   
    ...: for k in range(1, Nt):
    ...:   print('k',k) 
    ...:   for i in range(1, k):
    ...:     print('i',i)
    ...:     for j in range(1, Nx-1):
    ...:       print('j',j)   
    ...:       Sigma[i,j] += u[i+1,j] - u[i,j]   # <== change here
    ...:   print(Sigma)
    ...:   
k 1
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
k 2
i 1
j 1
j 2
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. 17.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
k 3
i 1
j 1
j 2
i 2
j 1
j 2
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  34.   0.   0.]
 [  0. -19.  -1.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]
k 4
i 1
j 1
j 2
i 2
j 1
j 2
i 3
j 1
j 2
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  51.   0.   0.]           # 3*17
 [  0. -38.  -2.   0.]           # 2* (-19 -1)
 [  0.  10.   6.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Not knowing what you are aiming at, I can't say whether that makes any more sense.

Comment: hpaulj- Thank you very much for your explanations. I am grateful for that. I understand SymPy better now. Yes,`u[i+1, j]-u[i, j]` is a difference between two different points in a 2D coordinate system. Actually, my main term is `u[k, j]`. I need to convert `u[i, j]` to `u[k, j]` using sum limits. So I can continue to calculate the whole equation. Because the sum includes another complex term in it. And this sum is  the left side of my equation. And the right side of the equation depends on `u[k, j]`. Furthermore, `k` is a time axis index, and `j` is a space axis index.

Comment: When I used `u[1:,j]-u[:-1,j]` for my last attempt sum(), I got 0.0 results again. I guess I can't convert `u` to `k`-based form.

Comment: Could the `i`'s not be iterating?

Comment: With in `for i in range(1, k):` `i` is a single number, 1, then 2, etc.  The `sum` (any of them) does not 'see' it as a range or iterator; it's just a number.  Have you studied any basic Python?  For the sympy `Sum`, you have to use something entirely different, a sympy symbol.  https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html.

Comment: Sorry for my simple question. I arbitrarily worked on it almost three years ago. I was studying mainly theoretical mathematics. My work suddenly evolved to require me to use Python. I'm trying to catch up quickly.

Comment: `sympy` does allow you to work with math, like other symbolic algebraic languages (MAPLE, etc).  But it works within Python.  So you have to be aware of where you are dealing with sympy expressions and symbols, and when it's just python.  Hopefully the gotcha's in sympy docs make this clear.  `numpy` is another addition to python, with more of a linear-algebra character (though LA purists still have problems using it).  The numeric and symbol packages are not as well integrated as in languages like MATLAB or Wolfram.  So mixing them is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your descriptive and kind response. I was aware of some of your comments about libraries. I will keep your advice in mind.

Comment: I added some calculations that I think reproduce your code in a meaningful way.  I'm not sure it accomplished much, but at least it shows the kind of detail that code development has to consider.  You can't just throw large calculations together and hope to get useful results.  You have to consider every detail, including the results at every iteration.

Comment: Thank you. Your edit helped me a lot. Yes, I realized that I needed to think about every detail. - I need to start function `u` with the `sin` effect. When I use `ones()` it gives the same elements. Hence the difference is zero. I cannot use `zeros()` and `empty()` too. Then, how can I initialize `u` with the `sin` effect and obtain the difference of `u`s at different points? I think I can't get a random numpy array for this. This gives me unpredictable results, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```py
for k in range(1, Nt): 
  for i in range(1, k):
    for j in range(1, Nx-1):   
      #define sum
      Sigma[i, j] = sum(u[_+1][j] - u[_][j] for _ in range(0, k))
      print(Sigma[i, j])
```

Although you could write `Sum(u[_+1[j] - u[_], (_, 0, k)).doit()`, the built-in `sum` is really what you are trying to do: an elementwise summation of literal values, not a summation of symbolic terms like `Sum(1/x, (x, 0, 5))` -- there does not need to be an `x` array for SymPy to figure out that sum since the limits indicate what the values of `x` are going to be. In your case you have the values in an array already.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, when I used the method you demonstrated, I received a 0.0 result once more. I cannot escape this result. I do not understand, whereas `u[i+1, j]` and `u[i, j]` two different points in a 2D coordinate system. Besides, what is the meaning of underscore `u[_]` ?

Comment: Could you please read my response to @hpaulj in case it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your `u` is a matrix of zeros (matrix of 1s multiplied by `sin(pi)`, which is 0). What do you want `u` to be?

Comment: The `_` is a python variable chosen to emphasize its insignificance outside of this context. I could have used anything not already in use, e.g. `ix`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the term `_`. Here, `u` includes ones and `Sigma` includes zeros. But I understand why the difference is zero. Because every element of `u` is the same. But I do not know how I can add `sin` behavior to the `u` for initializing. Do you have any advice for this?

Comment: Change Nx and Nt to 2 and print out `u`: `u = np.ones((Nt, Nx)) * np.sin(np.pi)`. Lacking information about what you are trying to do, I have no advice.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I already did this and got the same element for the array, whatever the array's dimension. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If I wanted values of `sin(i+j)` in the matrix I would do this in SymPy: `u = Matrix(Nt,Nx,lambda i,j:sin(i+j).n(3))` where the `.n(3)` evaluates them to 3 digits.